# Using Rblpapi via rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2

I can successfully use the Rblpapi from R:

```
> library("Rblpapi")
> conn <- blpConnect(host='myhost', port=18194)
> bds("SPX Index", "INDX_MEMBERS")

Member Ticker and Exchange Code
500 XYL UN
501 YHOO UW
502 YUM UN
503 ZBH UN
504 ZION UW
```

However, I can't use it from Python:

```
>>> from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
>>> r = importr('Rblpapi') 
>>> r.blpConnect(host='myhost', port=18194)
>>> print r.bds('SPX Index', 'INDEX_MEMBERS') 
NULL
```

The blpconnect() call seems to work (errors are thrown if the service isn't available), but I'm at a loss on how to debug this further.

Comment: What we return are standard data.frame objects which rpy2 _should_ transfer just fine.  But I know the R (and C++) side of things and less about how you receive it in Python...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misspelled INDX_MEMBERS

```
print r.bds('SPX Index', 'INDX_MEMBERS')
```

works as expected

Comment: Who is the 'You' here?

Answer (score 1):

Why?  Bloomberg gives you plenty of [Python APIs ready-made](http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/).

Comment: I'm using the desktop API from linux, which isn't supported

Comment: I don't follow. What is or isn't supported?